# nginx - CPU usage goes to 100% and php5-fpm stops when processing concurrent requests

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm, php5

I am processing php file with nohup command so that it should run in background.

But when I process more than 20 nohup commands then cpu usage goes to **100%** and **php5-fpm** crashes results in **connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed**

What's the solution for this?

Comment: That depends on what's broken, and you have not told us that. Check all of your logs, system state, etc.

Comment: `connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed` is itself an error log for nginx and `cpu usage goes to 100%` is system state :) ..and it seems php5-fpm crashes after some time!

Comment: Are you running php cli files with nohup or are they nothing to do with php?

Answer (score 0):

please check your FPM logs - "why is fpm crashing"
probably an application is running "crazy" (loops etc) and crashes your FPM.

connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed 
=> that's a normal error because the .sock isnt available anymore (fpm is crashed..)